# 404 issue in two htaccess in root domain and subfoler

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
My root domain htaccess:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{`HTTP_HOST`} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `https://%1/$1` [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` [R=301,L]

In my subfolder htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} `^(www\.example\.com)?$`
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `https://example.com/subfolder/$1` [R=301,L]
```

Wehn I type in `example.com/any-wrong-url`, it will redirect to 404 page, that is correct.

But when I type in `example.com/subfoler/any-wrong-url` it can not redirect to 404 page. Where do I something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this without creating any conflict or redirect is:

Use `/subfolder/` instead of root `/` on the RewriteBase like this:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

Copy the `404.php` inside the `subfolder`.

The complete code will look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} `^(www\.example\.com)?$`
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `https://example.com/subfolder/$1` [R=301,L]
```

This should work.